# Rails paper clip search file name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a requirement for users to be able to search file names uploaded by paperclip. Looking at an uploaded document looks like this...

```
2.0.0-p353 :002 > d=Document.last
  Document Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "documents".* FROM "documents"   ORDER BY "documents"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Document id: 5, name: "hampton_george_27_70", transcription: "Asheville Nov 8th 1853 received of James A. Patton...", created_at: "2014-08-22 16:10:19", updated_at: "2014-08-22 16:37:51", document_file_name: "hampton_george_27_70.jpeg", document_content_type: "image/jpeg", document_file_size: 519652, document_updated_at: "2014-08-22 16:10:19"> 
2.0.0-p353 :003 > d.document_file_name
 => "hampton_george_27_70.jpeg"
```

But these are no traditional rails type models, so how would I go about searching them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Document` appears to be a model, so you can query it. For example, to search for documents with "george" in the file name:

```
search_term = "george"
documents = Document.where(['document_file_name LIKE ?', "%#{search_term}%"])
```

Comment: Document.where('document_file_name LIKE ?', "%#{search_term}%").first